# How to serve a 3rd-party web site through my proxy, but alter content before it is displayed?

Tags: apache-2.2, proxy, squid, mod-proxy

I would like to fetch a remote web site, alter the contents slightly, and then display the final, altered contents to the end-user. Is this possible, and what would be the best way to go about doing this?

We are running Apache. Is it possible to accomplish this using mod_proxy? It doesn't appear so. What about Squid-Cache?

Any tips you can provide on this topic would be appreciated.

Comment: It *has* to be mentioned: The [upsidedown-ternet](http://www.ex-parrot.com/pete/upside-down-ternet.html)

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use Squid, then you will need to look into using ICAP filters for content adaptation.

http://wiki.squid-cache.org/SquidFaq/ContentAdaptation
http://wiki.squid-cache.org/Features/ICAP

Comment: This looks to be exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: @tambler Don't forget to come back and accept Matt's answer if it ends up working for you!